# Which pattern of getting infromation in Spring Boot Application @RestController is better and how to specify ANY @Mapping?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have **@RestController** in Spring Boot Application.

```
@PutMapping("{table}/{key}")
    public void update(@PathVariable("tables") String tableName,
                               @PathVariable("key") String key,
                               @RequestBody Entity entity) {
    ... 
    }
```

It's more convinient to transform this mapping into:

```
@PutMapping("{table}/{key}")
        public void update(@RequestBody Entity entity) {
        ... 
        }
```

and expect that information from **@PathVariable** would be **inside @RequestBody**.

**Reason**: I have **another @RestController** in which I recieve `AnotherEntity anotherEntity`. This architecture style permit me to create **generic hierarchy** in service layers

**Question 1**: Isn't a bad pattern? Is it quite good as perfect **REST** service or I should avoid It?
**Question 2**: In this case I don't use *@PathVariable* and I just need to specify ***someWord/SomeOtherWord*** as *@PutMapping* *path*. Is there some way to specify something like ***any/any*** without intellij inspection that I should use It?

Update: an example of architecture

```
public abstract class Validator<T> {
    public abstract void validate(T t);
}

public class FirstEntityValidator extends Validator<FirstEntity> {
     public void validate(FirstEntity entity){
     ...
     }
}

public class SecondEntityValidator extends Validator<SecondEntity> {
     public void validate(SecondEntity entity){
     ...
     }
}

public abstract class EntityService<T> {

    private Validator<T> validator;

    public EntityService(Validator<T> validator){
      this.validator = validator;
    }
}

public class FirstEntityService extends EntityService<FirstEntity> {

    public FirstEntityService(FirstEntityValidator<FirstEntity> validator){
       super(validator);
    }
}

public class SecondEntityService extends EntityService<SecondEntity> {

    public SecondEntityService(SecondEntityValidator<SecondEntity> validator){
       super(validator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid something like this. 
You should separate your REST Controllers like you separate your Services.
In case that you need to change something for just one entity you need to refactor everything anyway or produce some ugly code.

I think what you are trying to do is to expose your Repositories as a REST Webservice.
Spring can handle this for you.
Check this out:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

Use interfaces.
Don't use any abstract classes.
It is not necessary and can be very difficult to handle in bigger projects

This would be better:

```
public interface class Validator<T> {
  void validate(T t);
}

public class FirstEntityValidator implements Validator<FirstEntity> {
   public void validate(FirstEntity entity){
   ....
   }
}


public class SecondEntityValidator implements Validator<SecondEntity> {
   public void validate(SecondEntity entity){
   ....
   }
}

public interface EntityService{

 //your methods....

}

public class FirstEntityService implements EntityService{

    private FirstEntityValidator validator;

    public FirstEntityService(FirstEntityValidator validator){
        this.validator = validator;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is one more problem - information from @ RequestBody and @ PathVariable could be different. You said about possible changes, but if I have 2 services for 2 different entities(service is something abstract, It can be distributed service, caching service etc.), and they have the same method? The difference is  the only one - parameter type. On the one hand I have copypaste. On the other hand, if I use AbstractService with T type I can have problems in the future. It looks like both options aren't quite good

Comment: Don't use abstract Services. Use composition. This will help you a lot for the future. Read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: but what about The Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: This is something what I learned in my last big project. Inheritance is should not be used anymore. You can do everything in composition which makes your project more maintainable

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/the-single-responsibility-principle.html

I think this is what developers learned over the last 10 years.
Inheritance can be useful. But in nearly all cases composition is the better choice

Comment: I just want to specify if it's suitable to my example. I added an example in the question, Is it a bad architecture? I hide all behind the general interface and avoid copypaste, but I am not experienced and realy wonder about It. Could you check, please?

Comment: I have the last question - in your answer you specified  validator  as FirstEntityValidator type inside the service. Why didn't you specify It as Validator intreface type?

Comment: You can do this of course. I just wanted to show you that you use the specific implementation in that service